# Capture Audio Phonegap error code 3

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating an app with audio recording, i tried to implement this example code:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio

But when click on the button an error appears: Code error 3. According to documentation this errors appears when you exit the recording aplicacion before you record anything, but when i click on the button the recording app is not launched it goes directly to error function.

Capture video works fine.

Using Phonegap 3.0.0 or 2.9.0 with  Phonegap Build.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Audio</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Called when capture operation is finished
//
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureAudio() {
    // Launch device audio recording application,
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 audio clips
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
}

// Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="captureAudio();">Capture Audio</button> <br>
</body>
```

Comment: Include the actual code you're using in this question.

Comment: I got the same error. Did you solve it somehow?

Comment: I also have this error.

Comment: I just discovered the same problem just in Android, any solution?

Comment: Not yet, according to Phonegap support, the issue was resolved by Cordova guys, but this weekend i tried again and still getting code error 3.

Comment: I also having this issue and still not figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an exactly answer to your problem, but a working alternative.

Instead of using *org.apache.cordova.media-capture* I tried **org.apache.cordova.media**.

Here is a small example:

```
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.amr";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
        },

        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
        });

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        mediaRec.stopRecord();
    }, 10000);
}
```

Unfortunaly each device uses their own audio codec and in case of Android it is the AMR Codec. I was able to listen to the record using [MPC (Windows)](http://mpc-hc.org/). But if you want to upload the file and share it with other users, you'll have to [convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812050/564000).

If you do not find the `myrecording.amr` file: It is located on devices' root. I did not figure out how to store files temporary in the application cache folder itself, which is existing.

A 10 second recording has < 20kb size.

```
AMR 8000Hz mono 12kbps [Audio]
```

Which is very bad quality. Unfortunaly there seems to be no possibility to increase the quality.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be that there's no application that is handling the RECORD_SOUND intent.

I used this one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brightattic.soundrecorder&hl=en

(I have no endorsement for it other than it worked in my test)