# AMR audio not playing in browser, html generated via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Via javascript, I am trying to create the HTML and play an audio file but it's not playing.

If I download that same file and play it via a media player, it plays. My attempt is as below.

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "/files/chat-space/4928f76ff3258fcca32bb75d5d043237";
audio.play();
```

Is there any way to play this audio inside the browser, even using some other js-supported media player?

Comment: That URL doesn't look like a direct link to an audio file, are you sure it's not a redirect to another URL?

Comment: Try to set `audio.onerror=function(e) {console.log(e)}` and look at the console to see what's happening. I also would try to add a source with type set.

Comment: It's throwing an error

Answer (score 2):

Writing the error you're receiving by @ZeroWorks comment would make it much easier, and without an actual example I can only answer it as a guess.

I assume the error you're getting is "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."

I don't know what you're trying to do, but one solution for that could be 'forcing' the client to interact with the document using a button element.

For example:

```
<script>
    function onClick() {
        var audio = document.createElement("audio");
        audio.src = "./mediaFile.mp3";
        audio.play();
    }
</script>
```

Then have the following button element:

```
<button onclick="onClick()"> Click me </button>
```

If this is not your issue please try to explain it more precisely.

Comment: It's actually inside the click event of the html

Comment: @M.Cooper So can you state the error you're getting with actual code examples?

Comment: bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: [audio]
returnValue: true
srcElement: null
target: null
timeStamp: 30102.639999997336
type: "error"
__proto__: Event

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audio class in JS

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3'); // file must be having mp3 format
audio.play();
```

Comment: Actually the path for the audio url is "/files/chat-space/4928f76ff3258fcca32bb75d5d043237"

Comment: Are you allowed sound access on your browser ?

Comment: yes. I tested for some dummy urls for audio files

Comment: I need to play whatever the url with any extension coming from the backend to play in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        var audio = document.createElement("audio");
        var asrc = document.createElement("source");
        asrc.setAttribute('src', "/files/chat-space/4928f76ff3258fcca32bb75d5d043237");
        audio.appendChild(asrc);
        audio.play();
    });
</script>
```

Notes:

The `window.addEventListener('load')` tells the page not to try playing the audio until all HTML and resources are loaded/available.

The audio tag does not have a `src=` attribute — it has a child element, `<source>`, and *that* element has the `src=` attribute.

FWIW, I just tested the above code on a live server, using a standard mp3 audio file. If this code does not work for you, first try it with a standard .mp3 file *(to ensure the problem is not with specifying the audio file)*.

If it still doesn't work, please tell us more about your environment.

See:

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_audio.asp

Comment: Still not playing. Actually the problem is the audio source url coming from the backend. Even it can download and play using our installed media player in the machine, it will not play for default js audio player I think.

Comment: Is the audio regularly generated? Can you run it through a converter? Here is an AMR to MP3 converter plugin that should work with any backend language, with example code to use it via PHP : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428624/convert-audio-files-in-php